# Regularised Logistic regression in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, logistic-regression

I am using the below code for logistic regression with regularization in python. Its giving me 80% accuracy on the training set itself.

I am using minimize method 'TNC'. With BFG the results are of 50%. 
What is the ideal method(equivalent to fminunc in Octave) to use for gradient descent?
How can I increase or decrease iteration?
What is the default iteration?
Any other suggestion/approach to improve performance?

The same algo in Octave with fminunc gives 83% accuracy on the training set.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as op
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
from pylab import scatter, show, legend, xlabel, ylabel
from numpy import loadtxt, where
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1 + np.exp(-z));

def Gradient(theta,X,y,l):
    m,n = X.shape
    #print("theta shape")
    #print(theta.shape)
    theta = theta.reshape((n,1))
    thetaR = theta[1:n,:]
    y = y.reshape((m,1))
    h = sigmoid(X.dot(theta))
    nonRegGrad = ((np.sum(((h-y)*X),axis=0))/m).reshape(n,1)
    reg = np.insert((l/m)*thetaR,0,0,axis=0)
    grad = nonRegGrad + reg
    return grad.flatten();

def CostFunc(theta,X,y,l):
    h = sigmoid(X.dot(theta))
    m,n=X.shape;
    #print("theta shape")
    #print(theta.shape)
    theta = theta.reshape((n,1))
    thetaR = theta[1:n,:]
    cost=np.sum((np.multiply(-y,np.log(h))-np.multiply((1-y),np.log(1-h))))/m
    reg=(l/(2*m))* np.sum(np.square(thetaR))
    J=cost+reg
    return J;


def predict(theta,X):
    m,n=X.shape;
    return  np.round(sigmoid(X.dot(theta.reshape(n,1))));

data = np.loadtxt(open("ex2data2.txt","rb"),delimiter=",",skiprows=1)
nr,nc = data.shape
X=data[:,0:nc - 1]
#X=preprocessing.scale(X)
#X=np.insert(X,0,1,axis=1)
y= data[:,[nc - 1]]

pos = where(y == 1)
neg = where(y == 0)
scatter(X[pos, 0], X[pos, 1], marker='o', c='b')
scatter(X[neg, 0], X[neg, 1], marker='x', c='r')
xlabel('Microchip Test 1')
ylabel('Microchip Test 2')
legend(['Passed', 'Failed'])
show()
storeX=X
poly = PolynomialFeatures(6)
X=poly.fit_transform(X)
#print(X.shape)
m , n = X.shape;
initial_theta = np.zeros((n,1));
#initial_theta = zeros(shape=(it.shape[1], 1))
l = 1

# Compute and display initial cost and gradient for regularized logistic
# regression
#cost, grad = cost_function_reg(initial_theta, X, y, l)

#def decorated_cost(theta):
#    return cost_function_reg(theta, X, y, l)

#print fmin_bfgs(decorated_cost, initial_theta, maxfun=400)
print("Calling optimization")
Result = op.minimize(fun = CostFunc, 
                                 x0 = initial_theta, 
                                 args = (X, y,l),
                                 method = 'TNC',
                                 jac = Gradient);
optimal_theta = Result.x;
print(Result.x.shape)
print("optimal theta")
print(optimal_theta)
p=predict(optimal_theta,X)
accuracy = np.mean(np.double(p==y))
print("accuracy")
print(accuracy)

    enter code here
```

Comment: That looks fishy as the problem of l2-regularized logistic-regression (as i interpret your code) is a convex optimization problem and therefore all optimizers should output the same results (if local-optimum convergence is guaranteed which is common). TNS is one of the less accurate approaches which could explain some differences, but BFG should not fail that badly. Try it without giving the gradient explicitly and if that works better, your gradient is probably wrong. Also keep in mind, that these methods are technically not called gradient-descent.

Comment: Thanks @sascha. Is there any OOB Gradient Descent? To try without giving gradient- does that mean not to provide the gradeint function at all? Also can you suggest me how to plot the boundary?

Comment: Removed the gradient function and tried with BFGS and TNT. Accuracy dropped to 51%

Comment: I don't know what you mean by OOB Gradient Descent. Trying without gradient means not passing it with args and finite-diff-based approximation will be used automatically. Every experiment so far tells me that something is very wrong! Turn on verbose-mode of the optimizers and check the output. Check also your cost-function. Check sklearns examples for some boundary-plots or create a new question for that.

Comment: I did a boundary plot with Contour and it looks good(similar to my octave code. Here's the code.
def plotDecisionBoundary(theta,X,y):
 u = np.linspace(-1, 1.5, 50)
 v = np.linspace(-1, 1.5, 50)
 z=np.zeros((len(u),len(v)))
 poly = PolynomialFeatures(6)

 for i in range(0,len(u)):
  for j in range(0,len(v)):
   z[i][j] = ((poly.fit_transform([[u[i],v[j]]])).dot(theta))

 z=z.T
 #plt.figure()
 CS=plt.contour(u,v,z)
 
 plt.show()
 
 
 return z;